# Turn non decimal number into decimal number

Tags: php

I would like to know (as I current don't know and can't find the answer) how to turn a number without a decimal point into a number with a decimal point.

Here is what I would like to happen.

```
Input         Output
1.20          1.20
1234          0.1234
0.23456       0.23456
4321          0.4321
```

So basically I need a PHP function that accepts an input number (from a form field, variable or whatever) and if a whole number add 0. (zero dot) to the beginning. If the input number already has a decimal leave as is (I will number_format afterwards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple solution should do it.

```
function to_decimal($in){
    return (stripos($in, ".")!==false)? $in: "0.".$in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with [is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)

```
if (!is_float($input))
{
  $result = "0." . $input
}
```

Comment: Form field hardly passes typed value. They are usually string. and `is_float("12.4")` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function dPoint($number)
{
    if(is_float($number))
    {
    return $number;
    }
    else
    {
    return "0.".$number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Form field hardly passes typed value. They are usually string. and `is_float("12.4")` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution without lame string concatenation

```
function leadingZero($num) {
  if (!ctype_digit($num)) {
     return $num/pow(10, strlen($num));
  }
  return $num;
}
// php> =leadingZero(4652)
// 0.4652
// php> =leadingZero(0.2)
// 0.2
```

Comment: Form field hardly passes typed value. They are usually string. and `is_float("12.4")` is `false`.

Comment: `$num/pow(10, strlen($num))` is an expensive operation.